# Is it possible to map 2 tables to one single model using EF 6?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

The model Customer is mapped to Customers table. Is it possible to also map to another table named OldCustomers using the same model? There is no relation key between the tables and not looking for data normalization. Just need this other exactly model/table structure. In case this is not supported, what would be the best option?

Comment: Both tables have the same structure?

Comment: Yeah. As per the post: "Just need this other exactly model/table structure."

Answer (score 1):

override `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`  in the class which inherits from `DbContext` and then you can do the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyCoolModel>().ToTable("MyTab1");
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyCoolModel>().ToTable("MyTab2");

}
```

Comment: From RaFile class, (that already created a RaFiles table), I need to create a second table named ReFiles.
If I understood you correctly, all I got was the existing RaFiles table renamed to ReFiles.
Here is what I did:
          protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<RaFile>().ToTable("RaFiles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RaFile>().ToTable("ReFiles");
        }

Comment: can you please update your question? @BenJunior it's difficult to read